# Order tables in prestashop when should be it created?

Tags: paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

When should actually an order must be created in PrestaShop, We integrated a local payment module which will redirect to there page and after entering card details and validating the payment it returns  back , and it creates an order at that time.
My problem is that if the payment is declined , (or if I close the browser when the payment is processing  in the payment page ) order is not created in the ps_order table but cart is created  and if I query the bank  with another WEB service the payment response is success for that cart_id and id_order is 0,
but I dont have an order or entry in ps_order table created in my ps_order table  .How to cater this scenario?

Is it correct to create the order (insert into the order table )before payment processing and put current_state field as 3 status 3 means Processing in progress and change the current_state field if the payment is success or not.

select * from ps_orders

this is how the payemnt module does

```
if($reponseParameters[8]=='00000'){
                // Update the Respose to the ps_networkonline_payment 

                    $sql_response = " UPDATE `"._DB_PREFIX_."networkonline_payment` SET response = '".$text."' , `status` = '".$reponseParameters[4]."', error_code = '".$reponseParameters[8]."' WHERE order_id = '".$cart->id."' ";
                    Db::getInstance()->execute($sql_response);

                // Create Order In prestashop pass the values to order-confrimation class 
                    $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);
                    $this->module->validateOrder($cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $this->module->displayName, 'Transaction Reference: ' . $reponseParameters[5], array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);

                // Update the ps_order_payment table to make the PrestaShop Payment success 
                     $q_orders  = 'SELECT `reference` FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders WHERE `id_cart` = ' . (int) $cart->id;

                    if ($r_orders = Db::getInstance()->getRow($q_orders)){
                        Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_payment` SET `transaction_id` = \'' . pSQL($reponseParameters[5]) . '\' , `card_brand` = \'' . pSQL($reponseParameters[7]) . '\' WHERE `order_reference` = \'' . pSQL($r_orders['reference']) . '\'');                         
                    }


                    Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);           
                return;     
            }else{

                $this->error = $reponseParameters[9];//$this->module->getErrorMessage($object->error_code);
                $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH); 
                $this->module->validateOrder($cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR'), $total, $this->module->displayName, $this->error, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);

            }


        }else{

            //fail
            $this->error = $reponseParameters[9];//$this->module->getErrorMessage($object->error_code);
            $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH); 
            $this->module->validateOrder($cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR'), $total, $this->module->displayName, $this->error, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);

        }


}
```

Comment: In code example you have two "else" blocks with same code, but no "if" for the second "else". But anyway, if I understood correctly, the problem is when external service returns error code, your module do not create the order, right? Order is creating in *PaymentModule::validateOrder* method, did you try to debug this part? I mean if you have no data in DB then something goes wrong

Comment: but my question is when will the order table must be populated with order (order creation happen when ) when it goes to payment pages  and returns or before it goes to the payment page

Comment: yes, you can create/validate order and then change the status.

Answer (score 0):

What payments modules usually have is a way for the bank to query your website when your customers are redirected to their platform, this way the order is created on your side no matter what happens on their side (leaving you with a freshly created order with a state like "pending payment").

Then the order is updated on the customer's return to your website, by a call from the bank (be it with a status "blocked", "cancelled", or "payment accepted").

Comment: So  you mean  to say create the order  when it redirects to the payment page until waiting for the response of the payment , Is there any example of any payment module  how  do they do this ?

Comment: nah, what I mean is that some most payment module allow you to have an automated response, where a request is sent to your server whenever your customer reaches there platform, thus allowing you to create a "fresh" order.

Comment: That means when  it reached there site the payment module have to create a fresh  order  and make the order state as " pending payment "? In our case this does not happen's and if in some case if I close the browser when i reach there platform/page there is no order created so this is wrong right??